# Child class can't acess data from parent class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I've got the following code , where i define some operations to be done within a class and its variables:

```
namespace PPF_Converter_v10
{

    public class ProgramStuff
    {
        protected List<String> OpenedFiles { get; private set; }
        protected List<String> ValidFiles { get; private set; }
        protected List<String> InvalidFiles { get; private set; }
        protected List<String> FileData { get; private set; }
        protected string FileContents { get; private set; }
        public ProgramStuff()
        {
            OpenedFiles = new List<string>();
            ValidFiles = new List<string>();
            InvalidFiles = new List<string>();
            FileData = new List<string>();
            FileContents = string.Empty;
        }


    public void SelectFiles()
        {
            using (var FileSelect = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                FileSelect.Multiselect = true;
                FileSelect.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer);
                FileSelect.Filter = "PPF Files (*.ppf)|*.ppf|CIP Files (*.cip)|*.cip";
                FileSelect.Title = "Seclect a PPF or CIP File";
                DialogResult dr = FileSelect.ShowDialog();
                if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    foreach(var File in FileSelect.FileNames)
                    {
                        OpenedFiles.Add(File);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public void ReadFiles()
        {
            foreach(var File in OpenedFiles)
            {
                using (var fs = new FileStream(File, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
                {

                    FileContents = string.Empty;
                    var len = (int)fs.Length;
                    var bits = new byte[len];
                    fs.Read(bits, 0, len);
                    // Dump 1024 bytes per line
                    for (int ix = 0; ix < len; ix += 1024)
                    {
                        //drawTextProgressBar(ix, (int)fs.Length);

                        var cnt = Math.Min(1024, len - ix);
                        var line = new byte[cnt];
                        Array.Copy(bits, ix, line, 0, cnt);

                        // Convert non-ascii characters to .
                        for (int jx = 0; jx < cnt; ++jx)
                            if (line[jx] < 0x20 || line[jx] > 0x7f) line[jx] = (byte)'.';
                        //Creating a big string with output
                        FileContents += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(line);
                    }
                    FileData.Add(FileContents);
                }
            }
        }
        public void FileDefiniton()
        {
            foreach(var File in FileData)
            {

                bool b = File.Contains("/HDMZoneCoverageValue") && File.Contains("/CIP3AdmInkColors");
                if(b)
                {
                    ValidFiles.Add(File);
                }
                else
                {
                    InvalidFiles.Add(File);
                }
            }

        }
        public string XMLOutputFolder()
        {
            string XMLOutput = string.Empty;
            using (var XMLOut = new FolderBrowserDialog())
            {
                XMLOut.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
                XMLOut.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
                DialogResult dr = XMLOut.ShowDialog();
                if(dr == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    XMLOutput = XMLOut.SelectedPath;
                }
                return XMLOutput;
            }
        }
        public void ConvertedPPFFolder(string ConvertedPPF)
        {
            using (var ConvFolder = new FolderBrowserDialog())
            {
                ConvFolder.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
                ConvFolder.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
                DialogResult dr = ConvFolder.ShowDialog();
                if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    ConvertedPPF = ConvFolder.SelectedPath;
                }
            }
        }


    }//Closing class ProgramStuff
    //Creating a child class called FileManipulation - manipulate files
    public class FileManipulation: ProgramStuff
    {
        protected string PPFColors;
        protected string[] ColorsNames;

        public void ColorExtraction()
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ValidFiles.Count.ToString());

            foreach (var data in ValidFiles)
            {
                Regex ColorNameRegex = new Regex("CIP3AdmSeparationNames(.*)CIP3AdmPSExtent");
                var RegexAux = ColorNameRegex.Match(data);
                PPFColors = RegexAux.Groups[1].ToString();
                PPFColors = PPFColors.Replace("] def./", "").Replace("[", "").Replace(" (", "(").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "|");
                PPFColors = PPFColors.Remove(PPFColors.Length - 1, 1);
                ColorsNames = PPFColors.Split(new[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            }
        }
    }


}
```

Then, i have my form declaration, where i instantiate both and use them:

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private FileManipulation FileOp;
        private ProgramStuff GetFiles;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FileOp = new FileManipulation();
            GetFiles = new ProgramStuff();
        }       
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            GetFiles.SelectFiles();
            GetFiles.ReadFiles();
            GetFiles.FileDefiniton();
        }
```

The question is: i can do all operations i need using the instantiated class ProgramStuff (called GetFiles). But, right here, when i call a method from the child class:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileOp.ColorExtraction();
}
```

I can't acess data stored on the parent class. When debugging, the List called ValidFiles has 0 elements ; and there were elements added to it on the parent class. Is there way for me access those elements ? Thats the main point of my question.

Thanks !

Comment: Having trouble following what you intend... Are you thinking that the operations on the `GetFiles` object will be reflected within `FileOp` object? Because you didn't show any operations that load data into `ValidFiles` for `FileOp`. They are two *separate* objects with two *separate* sets of objects within them.

Comment: Button1_click loads data into ValidFiles. This part is working. Then , from FileOp , i would like to acess this data.

Comment: The two objects do not share `ValidFiles` between them. Each one gets its own `ValidFiles` list. Loading data into the `ValidFiles` list for `GetFiles` does absolutely nothing to the list within `FileOp`. I do not see why you are trying to use two variables here. The `FileManipulation` class can do everything its parent class, `ProgramStuff` can do. I would think you could just remove the `GetFiles` object altogether and simply use `FileOp` instead.

Comment: Okay. That was my first approach. But isn't it a bad practice to insert everything into only one class (considering OOP standards) ? If i just use one class everything will be working fine, i already know that. So, i should use Child Classes only to reuse a method or a variable - am i right ?

Comment: Still have problem dealing with `ppf` file? I think it take you nearly one month already :)

Comment: @Sakura  Hi ! No , no problem at ll. I already have a working version of the code (everything working perfectly even with a progress bar heh). I'm trying to improve the code and make it more OOP Oriented :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue you have is that you are instantiating Child and Parent Class:
            FileOp = new FileManipulation();
            GetFiles = new ProgramStuff();

and you are trying to use data stored in two different objects.

As I see it, you only have to instantiate Child Class:
            FileOp = new FileManipulation();

Then you will have to use FileOp on your code calling child and parents methods.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I just can't believe it was just that...worked like a charm ! Fantastic ! Thanks in advance. So, everytime i create a new child i'll have to instance only the child in order to access all elements ?

Comment: Glad to HELP ! Yes. If you have a parent and a child, when you create a child object, you can access parents method, protected, etc.Child always knows it parent...  :)